# modify the default options epson xp211 in cups

Tags: linux, drivers, cups, printer

I just installed an Epson xp211 using the cups web interface, selecting the XP-211-214-216-Series own cups driver, but this one doesn't have the ability to select the resolution and the ink mode of 4 colors/ 3 color composite.

How can this be enabled, or is there an equivalent driver that works and allows the options? I have CUPS 2.1.3.

Comment: where did you download the driver from? did you try Epson native drivers from epson.net?

Comment: I tryied the drivers from cups, I think its the epson escpr package